# atmosphere config param to close request after certain time

Tags: grails, atmosphere

Can some please tell me how can we specify the maximum time to keep websocket connection thread open  in atmosphere. I am using grails event push plugin to push events to client from server. I see that atmosphere connection remain open for long time. I want limit it to say 5 mins.

Answer (score 1):

which version of atmosphere you are using?  Which container ?

if you are using older version user atmosphere 2.x and If you using tomcat make sure org.atmosphere.cpr.cometSupport value is org.atmosphere.container.Tomcat7CometSupport

Comment: Actually I am using event-push plugin which internally uses atmosphere 1.0 I'll try to update and will check the result. Thanks for reply.